# Buscar datos de una ID con el evento onclick

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

Estoy realizando por medio de JavaScript y Ajax, buscar los datos de una ID de mi tabla al hacerle clic, que sucede al darle clic me muestra los resultados pero de todas las ID que están en esa tabla lo que intento es que solo me salga la información de la ID de la que le estoy haciendo clic y así si le doy a otro me muestre los datos de esa ID y así sucesivamente.

Este es el script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayBetado(val){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/web/sub/betado_stats.php?id=' + val,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#betado_perfil").html(html);
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#betado_perfil").offset().top},500,function(){
                    ultimoscroll=$(window).scrollTop();
                    animacion=false;
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Para el evento de `DisplayBetado(val)` realicé el botón de esta manera:

```
<tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="tr_1">
```

Entonces al hacer clic muestra el apartado de `betado_stats.php` que es este:

```
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
require_once('steam.php');

$dbTable = "amx_bans";
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
?>

<?php while ($betados = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <div class="betado_stats_info">
        <div class="user_info">
            <div class="info_prim">
                <div class="user_foto">
                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                </div>
                <div class="info_p">
                    <p class="p1">
                        Apodo :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo substr($betados['player_nick'], 0, 15);
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Status :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo $betados["player_id"];
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Perfil de Steam :
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($betados["player_id"]);?>">
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                ?>
                                https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($betados["player_id"]);
                            } ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Razón :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo $betados["ban_reason"];
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Administrador :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo $betados["admin_nick"];
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Fecha del Ban :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($betados["ban_created"]-14400));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($betados["ban_created"]-14400));
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Fecha de Expiración :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {
                                $diasBaneados = floor($betados["ban_length"] / 1440);
                                $horasBaneadas = floor($betados["ban_length"] / 60);
                                ?>
                                <?php if($betados["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php }
                                else if($betados["expired"] == 1)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Expirado
                                <?php }
                                else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                                <?php } 
                                else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                                <?php }
                                else if($betados["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo $betados["ban_length"] ?> minutos;
                                <?php } 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                Nunca
                            <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p2">
                        Pov Demo :
                        <span>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                Sin demo
                            <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="p1">
                        Math Hash :
                        <a>
                            <?php if($betados["bid"])
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                <span style=color:#999999;>No estaba en partido</span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no estas capturando el id

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
require_once('steam.php');
//almacenara la extension de la query
$ext_query = "";
// si esta definido el parametro id
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    // se asignara la extension de la query
    // con la clausula where + el id
    $ext_query = " where bid=".$_GET['id'];
}

$dbTable = "amx_bans";
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
// concatenamos el el where si esta definido id
// en caso contrario quedara igual
$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable .$ext_query ) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
?>
```

saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono perfectamente I LOVEEEEEEEEE